# Ionic content not showing after adding side menu

Tags: ionic-framework

I can inspect the content,
Content is showing in inspect element but not showing on screen.
it happens after adding side menu
Thanks.

```
          <ion-side-menus>
          <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-header-bar  class="bar-assertive">
            <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button icon button-clear ion-navicon-round" ng-click="toggleLeft()"></button>
            </div>
            <h1 class="title">Dial A Meat</h1>
            <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button icon ion-ios-cart" ></button>
            </div>
          </ion-header-bar>
          </ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-side-menu side="left">
              <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
                <h1 class="title"></h1>
              </header>
              <ion-content class="has-header">
                <ion-list>
                  <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/search">
                    Search
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/browse">
                    Categories
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
                    Products
                  </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
              </ion-content>
            </ion-side-menu>
          </ion-side-menus>


              <ion-content class="has-header has-footer" overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" style="background: url(img/AAJfSCTHDu8c7Ojl09g8_o-MEAT-facebook.jpg) no-repeat center;" ng-controller="homeCtrl" ng-init="getcategory()">
                      <div ng-repeat="x in category" >
                          <a  ng-click="order(x.id)" ng-controller="orderAMeatCtrl" style="dipsplay: inline-block; width: 100%; height: auto;">
                          <h1 style="">{{x.name}}</h1>

                              <img src="img/{{x.image}}" height="auto" width="100%">
                          </a>
                          <!--href="#/page1/order"-->
                      </div>
              </ion-content>
```

Comment: put your ion-content inside your ion-side-menu-content

Comment: Thanks for replying @pbo -if I put ion-content inside ion-side-mneu-content the content will shown in side-menu but i want content to show on main page not in side-menu

Comment: Can you describe your question a little bit more? Normally you put a ion-nav-view element inside your ion-side-menu-content and than display different content for each state... take a look at the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/) and this [example](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/QwamEW).